# Change shape color in an Altair legend

Tags: python, colors, legend, shapes, altair

Consider the following code adapted from [Altair website](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_bar_chart.html).

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})
brush = alt.selection(type='single')

alt.Chart(source).mark_point(filled=True).encode(
    x='a',
    y='b:Q',
    shape='a',
    color=alt.condition(brush, 
                        alt.Color('b:N', legend=alt.Legend(columns=2, symbolFillColor='blue')),
                        alt.value(None)),
).add_selection(brush)
```

Which outputs this plot:

[image]

When I click a datapoint all others disappear, which is OK.

**The problem** is in the **legend where shapes don't have a color**, because of  `alt.value(None))` .

How do I set a color other than invisible for the shapes inside the legend while maintaining the selection (when I click a datapoint that makes all the others disappear)?

I have tried  `symbolFillColor='blue'`, `symbolStrokeColor='blue'` but it doesn't change the shape color.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to set the default mark color:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})
brush = alt.selection(type='single')

alt.Chart(source).mark_point(filled=True, color='blue').encode(
    x='a',
    y='b:Q',
    shape='a',
    color=alt.condition(brush, 
                        alt.Color('b:N', legend=alt.Legend(columns=2)),
                        alt.value(None)),
).add_selection(brush)
```

[image]

The reason `symbolFillColor` and `symbolStrokeColor` didn't work is because you were applying them to the color legend, and those default colors will be overridden by the encoding.